# How to handle reused object in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, design-patterns, activerecord, architecture

- Note: note sure if this is the best title for the question / open to suggestions to edit for future value *

I have a multi-tenant rails application, which allows clients to use their own custom TLDs. So I can have:

www.clientA.com

www.clientB.com

www.clientC.com

etc....

For better or worse, my database (postgres) has a tenants table, which has approximately 60 columns with various settings & configurations for each tenant.  Some are simply flags, and some are large text values.

In `application_controller.rb` I have some logic to parse the URL, query the tenants table based on the domain and instantiate a `@current_tenant` object.  That `@current_tenant` object is available throughout the lifecycle of the page.  This happens on every. single. page. of my app.

While I have some heavy caching in place, this design still feels very wrong to me, and I am sure it can be improved.

Is there a best practice for this?  What is the best pattern to handle the @current_tenant object?  I am concerned about memory management.

Comment: How do you handle SSL?  I would think you would do something similar as with subdomains.  Check out this railscast.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: anytime there is ssl the TLD domain changes to https://clientname.myappdomain.com which has a wildcard SSL.  I am still looking up and loading that @current_tenant object in that scenario.

Comment: I think the answer depends on what kind of server you are using. Passenger for example will likely create seperate processes for every subdomain. If you're using Nginx as a proxy for Puma or Unicorn, you could lead every request to the same app instance, which will make it easier to share memory access.

I'm not sure what kind of stuff you're trying to cache (complex objects or just some strings to configure your app, etc - maybe some code examples would help), but a more generic way would be to use something like Memcached or Redis to share your cached values between instances.

Comment: I am using Unicorn (on Heroku).  I guess my issue/concern is that I am loading the @current_tenant object on every page request and it has about 60 properties on it, some flags, some large text values.  Is there a best practice for handling something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `current_tenant` is no different from `current_user` that is ubiquitous in Rails apps.

stop microoptimizing. unless you benchmarked it and it shows to be a major bottleneck (which it is not, I can assure you).

any minuscule performance improvement (if at all) will be offset by the increased complexity of code, caching problems and what not.

do. not. do. that. ;)

one thing though, do NOT do a before_filter that assigns `@current_tenant`, instead add a `current_tenant` method to the `application_controller` (or one of its concerns) that will cache the result for the remainder of the request:

```
def current_tenant
  @current_tenant ||= ....
end
```

Comment: can you clarify on your last statement?  I have a `before_filter :set_current_tenant` on the `application_controller`.  It is not on every controller of my app.

Comment: any thoughts on the above comment? @vitaly

Comment: it is almost always better to make a `lazy` helper method that will cache the result instead of the `before_action` that will "pre-set" it. several reasons:

- it is much easier this way, you do not need to even think about which action needs it and which not. you just use it and if it didn't run the query yet it will do it "at this moment", and if your action doesn't call it, then the query doesn't run.

- caching. for example, if you *only* need it from a cached fragment, then if you do it with a `before_action` it will do the query even if you have a cache hit.

Answer (score 1):

You could also cache the `@current_tenant` object using Rails cache, ie:

```
def current_tenant( host = request.host )
  Rails.cache.fetch(host, expires_in: 5.minutes) do
    Tenant.find_by(tld: host)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I haven't touched Rails for 3 years, so take this answer with the appropriate fistful of salt.)

> Is there a best practice for this? What is the best pattern to handle the @current_tenant object?

The best way I've seen this kind of stuff implemented is in PHP, rather than Ruby on Rails. More specifically, in the Symfony framework.

In a nutshell, a Symfony app's layout is like so:

```
/app    <-- app-specific Kernel, Console, config, cache, logs, etc.
/src    <-- app-specific source files
/vendor <-- vendored source files
/web    <-- public web folder for the app
```

To run multiple apps from the same code base, you'd basically go:

```
/app
/app2
/...
/src
/vendor
/web
/web2
/...
```

... and then point each domain to a different /web folder.

As I understand, it's possible to re-organize a Rail project's directory structure to something more or less equivalent. See this related answer in particular:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480207/417194

From there, you could theoretically boot up one instance of your app per tenant, each with their separate resources, hard-coded defaults, etc., while continuing to use a shared code base.

The next best option is, imo, what you're currently doing. Use memcached or equivalent to quickly map specific domain names to tenants, and fall back to a database query as necessary. I imagine you're doing this already, since you've "some heavy caching in place".

As an aside, you might find this related question, and the ones linked within it, interesting:

[Multiple applications using a single code base in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641653/multiple-applications-using-a-single-code-base-in-ruby)

(And FWIW, I ended up not sticking with PHP for multi-tenant apps. There was no magic bullet last I played with Ruby or Rails.)

With respect to memory usage, methinks don't worry too much about it: strictly speaking, you're looking up and creating the tenant object a single time per request. Even if doing so was dreadfully slow, cursory monitoring of where your app is actually spending time will reveal that it's negligible compared to innocuous looking pieces of code that get run a gazillion times per request.

Answer (score 1):

I designed an application that is doing basically exactly what you have described. Since you are loading a single object (even if on every page request), just make sure the query only returns the one row (current tenant) and doesn't do a crazy amount of joins. A single row query with a LIMIT applied to it is not going to bring down your site, even if requested hundreds of times a second. And regardless, if you are getting that type of traffic, you will have to scale your server anyways.

One thing that can be done to help, is to make sure your search column is indexed in the database. If you are finding the current tenant by url, index the url column.

Here is an example of what I did. I globalized the variable so this information is available in all controllers/models/views.

In my application controller:

```
before_filter :allocate_site


private

def allocate_site

  url = request.host_with_port
  url.slice! "www."

  # load the current site by URL
  $current_site = Site.find_by({:url => url, :deleted => false})

  # if the current site doesn't exist, we are going to create a placeholder
  # for the URL hitting the server. 
  if $current_site.nil?
    $current_site = Site.new
    $current_site.name = 'New Site'
    $current_site.url = url

    $current_site.save

  end
end
```

Comment: thanks!  is there a benefit to making it $current_site vs. @current_site?    should I be worried about memory management if the single row is fairly wide (60 columns, some of type text)?

Comment: $current_site makes it a global variable. This variable will be accessible in controllers, models, and views without having to recall it. If you use @current_site, this is an instance variable. It will only be available to controllers whom inherit from ApplicationController (and therefore the views as well). You will need to pass the variable to models. As for performance, I think you will just need to run some tests. My site object holds about 30 attributes and I haven't noticed any issues with speed (none that are any worse then what rails does already haha).

Comment: Aside from that, if your worried about constant db pulls, agios's response shows you how to cache it. The only difference being, I would expire the cache based on the objects updated_at attribute, that way the cache only needs to be rebuilt when the record changes.

Comment: I should add, I went with $ instead of @ just because I had a few processes that needed to be run always scoped by $current_site. I could have just as easily passed in @current_site to the model instead of using the global $current_site. You will need to determine what works best for you and your business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding extra gems to your application, I would recommend using [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment). This was done exactly to serve your purpose : handle rails application with multiple tenants.

This would present two advantages to your problem:

1. handling `@current_tenant` (or whatever you wish to name it) is done through a middleware, so you won't need to set it in your `ApplicationController`. Take a look at the [Switch on domain](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#switching-tenants-per-request) section of the `README` to see how it is done. (Note: `apartment` uses `Apartment.current_tenant` to refer to your `@current_tenant`.
2. The best part: in most case, you will not need `@current_tenant` anymore since `apartment` will scope all requests on the appropriate postgresql schema.